# Can I embed $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ with a partial order into $^\ast\mathbb{R}$ with the linear order?

Tags: order-theory, economics, nonstandard-analysis

Define a relation $\prec$ on  $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ as,

> For all $f, g \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} $, $f \prec g$, if for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $f(n) \leq g(n)$, and there exists a $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(m) < g(m)$.

Does there exist a function $u : \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} \to {^\ast\mathbb{R}}$ such that

> For all $f, g \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N} $,$f \prec g$ implies that $u(f) < u(g)$
>   ?

${^\ast\mathbb{R}}$ denotes [hyperreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number). I tagged economics, because this is an attempted extension of [utility representation theorem](http://press.princeton.edu/rubinstein/lecture2.pdf).

Comment: What is ${{}^\ast\Bbb R}$?

Comment: @Regret It seems these are [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).

Comment: @dtldarek Thank you for answering this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the construction of ${}^\ast\Bbb R$ properly, then the function defined as follows should work.

$$u(f)_n=\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)$$

Here $u(f)_n$ denotes the $n$-th member of the hyperreal $u(f)$. If $f\prec g$, then $u(f)_n<u(g)_n$ for all $n\ge m$. There are cofinitely many $n$ greater than $m$, so regardless of the choice of ultrafilter, $u(f)<u(g)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and sorry for my delay to response. As I can tell, I think your construction is correct.